# Is string.join faster with tuples or a list?

Tags: python, string, list, join, tuples

If I have the choice between

```
''.join( ['a', 'b'] )
```

and

```
''.join( ('a', 'b') )
```

which one should I use (which one is faster)? Does it matter?

Comment: Do you have huge lists/tuples or do you need to run this code a lot?

Comment: Perhaps it would be wise to run a benchmark under real-world conditions?

Comment: I think it makes no difference

Comment: @jsalonen I mostly have small lists/tuples. I was just curious how to write better code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are almost equivalent and you can always time your code using `timeit` module:

```
In [145]: small_lis,small_tup = ['a','b']*10, ('a','b')*10

In [146]: avg_lis,avg_tup = ['a','b']*1000, ('a','b')*1000

In [147]: huge_lis,huge_tup = ['a','b']*10**6, ('a','b')*10**6
```

Timing results when number of items are 20:

```
>>> %timeit ''.join(small_lis)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 987 ns per loop

>>> %timeit ''.join(small_tup)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1 us per loop
```

Average size(2000 items):

```
>>> %timeit ''.join(avg_lis)
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.5 us per loop

>>> %timeit ''.join(avg_tup)
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.8 us per loop
```

Huge size (2* 10**6 items):

```
>>> %timeit ''.join(huge_lis)
1 loops, best of 3: 79.9 ms per loop

>>> %timeit ''.join(huge_tup)
1 loops, best of 3: 77.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: Any reason you include the creation of the tuple or list in the timings?

Comment: looks like its only faster when you get to huge lists ... also so small a difference as to not be worth worrying about :) +1

Comment: Surprisingly (to me, since it is a linked list and advancing from one element to the next should be very fast), a `collections.deque` is about half as fast as either a `tuple` or a `list` in the 1000-element case.

Comment: @kindall Is that really suprising considering that `tuple`s and `list`s have been optimized so much?

Comment: Ehhh, `deque` is also written in C and pretty optimized. On further reflection I'd probably put it down to cache effects: the pointer to the next object is much more likely to be in the processor's cache when iterating over a list.